# Galaxy S7 display settings for gaming

Tags: samsung

In `Settings` > `Display and wallpaper`, there is an option for `Screen Mode` with options for:

1. Adaptive Display
2. AMOLED cinema
3. AMOLED photo
4. Basic

I set mine to `Basic` but regardless of this setting, when I launch games, it appears to switch to `Adaptive Display`.  Is there a way to disable this?  I'm not a fan of over-saturated colors and would like the display to remain in `Basic` mode when in games and media applications.

Answer (score 0):

I swear this was the first thing I tried but my 2nd attempt seemed to fix it.  Simply change the display option.  Save it.  Then change it back.

`Settings > Display and wallpaper > Screen mode`

A few things I also did while messing with it that might have had an impact:

1. turned `Game Launcher` app off an on
2. installed Google's `Play Games` app which seemed to force some other updates
3. rebooted the phone